# かな漢字変換の辞書を作りたいが、元にできる物をご存知無いでしょうか？

Tags: ios8

Realmに落とし込んで使いたいと思っています。
参考になるものや、元とできるものをご存知無いでしょうか？

内部辞書が使えれば一番なんですが。

一応これは、かな漢字変換には使えなそうです。
http://qiita.com/doraTeX/items/9b290f4e39f1e100558b

情報お持ちでしたら、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

かなり古いですが、下記のページが参考になると思います。

[フリーのかな漢字変換辞書たち]
   http://homepage2.nifty.com/baba_hajime/free-dic/

茶筌の辞書は、形態素分析に使われています。
また、松本研究室（茶筌の開発元）に辞書の情報があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。辞書を落としてみました。辞書の形式について検討が必要ですね。「名詞」とか「一般」とか・・・どう扱うかが、問題になってきました。

Answer (score 1):

どういう辞書をご期待なのかよくわかりません。
- 権利フリーで無償利用可能なのが良いとか
- NDA 契約を結んだ上で有償になるが、賢いのがいいとか
- どんなサイズを想定しているかとか

たとえば SKK Openlab http://openlab.ring.gr.jp/skk/index-j.html
たとえば tamago http://flex.phys.tohoku.ac.jp/texi/egg/egg_toc.html
たとえば Wnn (FreeWnn, OpenWnn)

ネタが古い・・・っすね。もっと新しいのがきっとあるはずですけどオイラこっち系は詳しくないっす。

Comment: 「権利フリーで無償利用可能なのが良い」というのが、楽でいいですが、こだわりません。
あとは、「変換エンジンの作りやすい」のがいいですが・・・

Social-IMEを今は使っていますが、これはうまく変換が帰ってきていいです。しかし、オンラインの辞書から卒業したいのです。通信条件に左右されます。サーバーダウンにも影響されます。
それで、なんとかしたいのです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

ご提案いただいたリンクも検討します。ありがとうございます。